# Can not find Admin button on GitLab

Tags: gitlab

In this GitLab docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html it has been mentioned that:

> You can change how often this happens or turn it off:
>
> On the top bar, select `Menu > Admin`. On the left sidebar, select Settings > Repository.

But when I open `Menu` but there is no `Admin` button. How can I add `Admin` button into `Menu` and also use it? Is it free to access using `Admin` option?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are an admin on your GitLab instance?

Comment: I am the only person on my GitLab shouldn't I be automatically admin? How could I make myself admin on the instance?

Comment: Not necessarily. When you first create GitLab, there is a default `root` account which is an admin, but all other users are normal users. You can promote yourself to an admin by using the `root` account or by [using the gitlab rails console](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-do-i-change-my-profile-to-admin/35888).

Comment: I am accessing GitLab through its GUI and `git` command , could I still able to access my account gitlab package as I understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easier with [GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#access-the-admin-area-from-the-left-sidebar) (December 2023)

> ### Access the Admin Area from the left sidebar
>
> Administrators can now access the Admin Area in one step, by using a link at the bottom of the left sidebar.
>
> Previously, you had to select **Search or go to** and then select **Admin Area**. This change should save you time when accessing the Admin Area.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_7/adminAreaLinkInNav.png -- Access the Admin Area from the left sidebar]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/admin_area.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/415854).

Comment: Could only find it by pressing search and Admin Area appeared in the search modal!

Comment: @sFritsch09 OK, but which version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: it's v16.8.1-ee

Comment: @sFritsch09 Strange, the new "Access the Admin Area" should be in effect.

Comment: Same here, on v16.7.0-ee and on v16.8.2-ee. Logging out and in didn't help. Had to manually add `/admin` to the URL, then it said "Re-authentication required". After reauthenticating there, the "Admin Area" button appeared.

Comment: @BastiaanVeelo Thank you for the feedback. That seems... cumbersome.

Comment: Reported: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/442428

Comment: @BastiaanVeelo Thank you. I will follow this issue with interest.

Answer (score 1):

The admin menu is restricted to GitLab administrators. If you do not see an Admin button, this most likely means you are not a GitLab Administrator. If you are using gitlab.com, this is the case for pretty much all gitlab.com users.

---

**Note: this references an older UI from the original time of writing of this answer (April 2022).** You will only see this UI if you are using an older version of GitLab or have opted out of the new UI in your user preferences. See [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729153/5747944) for reference using modern versions of GitLab.
However, the principles are still the same: you must be an admin to see the admin UI navigation elements.

---

If you are an admin, in modern versions of GitLab you should see the button at the bottom of the dropdown:

[image: admin button]

In older versions, the admin button is directly in the top bar.

If you are an admin on a self-hosted GitLab instance, you can also attempt to access the admin area directory directly at the path `/admin`. If you are logged in and get a 404, it means you are not an admin (or your instance has [admin mode setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_in_restrictions.html#admin-mode) enabled).

Note that this documentation is under the "Administration" section, meaning this is intended for (self-managed) administrators only. The docs could probably also be updated to make this more clear:

> ***Administrators*** can change how often this happens or turn it off:

Comment: I am a free-user using GitLab to work on my public and private repos but I do not host any gitlab instance. Is it possible to make myself admin for the private repos I own?

Comment: No, on gitlab.com only certain GitLab employees might be administrators. Administrators have instance-wide privileges across all groups. For all intents and purposes _every_ customer on gitlab.com is not an admin and cannot leverage any admin privileges. You'll also notice the docs designate these features as for "self-managed" instances only at the top of the page @alper

Comment: There is no more drop-down menu since a long time in Gitlab
as VonC explained, buttons had disapeared and has come back only in Gitlab 16.7

Comment: @XavDeb that's true, although it depends what version of GitLab you're running and if you've opted out of the new UI in your user preferences. As Von explains in his answer, the default view has changed in recent versions of GitLab to be in the sidebar. I just plan to keep my answer as-is to help users who may be using older versions of GitLab and/or those who have their user preferences set to use the old UI.